# "This Chalice Dungeon has been deleted from the server"?

Tags: bloodborne

I just created my first Chalice Dungeon, and I've been working on beating it. I haven't beat it yet.

But now when I check the Chalice Dungeon info, it says this message in red at the bottom.

Why? What's it do?

Answer (score 2):

Is it still playable? Then don't mind the message.

If it became unplayable, I guess the Glyph got corrupt or something. Try to make a new one. If it was made with a Chalice without the word "root" in it you will get the same dungeon anyway.

EDIT: I looked some more into it since I got the same message: Is it possible that your dungeon is more then a week/few weeks old? If so, it probably means because the dungeon is created some time ago, the game threw it away from the server. To make the Glyph available for a new dungeon. This means you can still play the dungeon, but none can join you since you're playing SinglePlayer when playing in the deleted dungeon (atleast thats what I think).

The reason why I think that, is because yesterday I saw some posts about people who lost their character after they stopped playing for a few weeks while their character was still inside the dungeon. And they all had the same message as you on their Chalice dungeon.

Comment: It's still playable. Can other players join me still? What does the message mean?

Comment: @Zeno, I guess people can still join you since you can play it too. Idk what the message means though, but I think you should just ignore it unless it pops-up again with other chalice dungeons.

Comment: @Zeno I edited my post, I think I found out what it means.